# JPA trying to force me to have a property and database column named 'id'

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a MySQL InnoDB database table with two columns named follower_user_id and followed_user_id, both of which make up the primary key.

I'm trying to map them in Spring Boot but error messages keep telling me I need a property named 'id'. But this table does not have an 'id' column.

What's more, the JPA even autocreates a column named 'id' in the table, definitely not what I want.

Basically when a row gets inserted into this table, the follower_user_id and followed_user_id get provided and the combination form the primary key. There is no autogenerated id.

How do I tell JPA that I don't need a property named 'id', that the forementioned columns make up the primary key and there is no autogenerated key? Thanks!

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable;

@Entity
@IdClass(FollowerId.class)
public class Follower extends AbstractPersistable<Long> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 23456789L;

    @Id
    private Long followerUserId;

    @Id
    private Long followedUserId;

    public Long getFollowerUserId() {
        return followerUserId;
    }

    public void setFollowerUserId(Long followerUserId) {
        this.followerUserId = followerUserId;
    }

    public Long getFollowedUserId() {
        return followerUserId;
    }

    public void setFollowedUserId(Long followedUserId) {
        this.followedUserId = followedUserId;
    }
}

import java.io.Serializable;

public class FollowerId implements Serializable {
    private Long followerUserId;
    private Long followedUserId;

    public FollowerId() {
    }

    public FollowerId(Long followerUserId, Long followedUserId) {
        this.followerUserId = followerUserId;
        this.followedUserId = followedUserId;
    }

    public Long getFollowerUserId() {
        return followerUserId;
    }

    public void setFollowerUserId(Long followerUserId) {
        this.followerUserId = followerUserId;
    }

    public Long getFollowedUserId() {
        return followerUserId;
    }

    public void setFollowedUserId(Long followedUserId) {
        this.followedUserId = followedUserId;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) (getFollowerUserId() + getFollowedUserId());
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof FollowerId)) return false;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        FollowerId pk = (FollowerId) obj;
        return pk.getFollowerUserId() == getFollowerUserId() && 
            pk.getFollowedUserId() == getFollowedUserId();
    }
}
```

The error I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Unable to locate property named id on com.mightyjava.model.FollowerId
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at com.mightyjava.Application.main(Application.java:12) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Unable to locate property named id on com.mightyjava.model.FollowerId
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyIndex(ComponentType.java:740) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.AttributeFactory$3.resolveMember(AttributeFactory.java:973) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.AttributeFactory$5.resolveMember(AttributeFactory.java:1024) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.AttributeFactory.determineAttributeMetadata(AttributeFactory.java:449) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.AttributeFactory.buildIdAttribute(AttributeFactory.java:128) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetadataContext.applyIdMetadata(MetadataContext.java:303) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetadataContext.wrapUp(MetadataContext.java:231) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.buildMetamodel(MetamodelImpl.java:82) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:890) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I cannot tell you exact reason for this, but i suggest that you should use "EmbeddedId" annotation because it is more readable than "IdClass".

Comment: Don't extend `AbstractPersistable` then, as that has a default `id` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, so looks like extending AbstractPersistable was the problem. This superclass was forcing me to have an ID property. I have removed this and things seem to be fine now.

I was borrowing some code I found online which was why I was extending it, but looks like I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

You want a composite primary key.

Create a class that represents the two values you want to make up the key. This is an embeddable id.

```
@Embeddable
public class FollowId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "followerUserId", nullable = false)
    private Long followerUserId;

    @Column(name = "followedUserId", nullable = false)
    private Long followedUserId;

}
```

Next, you can use this class as an ID in your entity.

```
@Entity
public class Follower implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private FollowId followId;

    //other stuff
}
```

You can access the specific parts of the ID like you would a regular object, ex:

```
Follower f = new Follower();
f.getFollowId().getFollowerUserId();
f.getFollowId().getFollowedUserId();
```

And in jpql you can access them like that as well:

```
select f from Follower as f where followId.followerUserId = 1 AND followId.followedUserId = 1;
```

EDIT:

**IdClass**

This seems to be another way to do composite keys that I am unfamiliar with. It looks like you need a class that represents the ID, and in your entity you must have fields that map to the values in the composite primary key. Then annotate the entity with @IdClass(), containing the class that represents the composite key. Something like this:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(FollowId.class)
public class Follower implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long followerUserId;

    @Id
    private Long followedUserId;

    //other stuff
}

public class FollowId implements Serializable {
    private Long followerUserId;
    private Long followedUserId;

    //other stuff

}
```

As I don't really use the @IdClass method, I encourage you to read further on it:

[IdClass example](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/01/jpa-idclass-example/)

[ObjectDB page](https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/IdClass)

Comment: Now getting the error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class com.mightyjava.model.Follower] does not define an IdClass

Comment: I have edited the answer to try and explain IdClass.

Comment: Found the issue, but your answer made me realize that extending AbstractPersistable might be the culprit since it was the only thing you weren't doing.

Comment: Cool. Keep in mind that JPA is pretty adamant about having an ID field listed. In all flavors of JPA I've used thus far, when actually persisting / creating the table, the ID column is autogenerated if it's missing (which you saw), so if the two fields you brought up do make up the primary key, it will help to make the composite key and annotate it accordingly.